# systemctl cannot access service file, Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, systemd, scheduling

On Fedora 35, I create my own service to schedule a backup. I have the script in /usr/local/bin/ and service files plus timer in /lib/systemd/system/

ls -an /usr/local/bin/ prints

`-rwxr--r--. 1 0 0 3360 Dec  1 18:31 backup.sh`

ls -an /lib/systemd/system/schedule-backup_root*

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 0 0 230 Dec  1 18:14 /lib/systemd/system/schedule-backup_root.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 0 0 388 Dec  1 16:49 /lib/systemd/system/schedule-backup_root.timer
```

but then when I start the service systemctl start schedule-backup_root.service

```
Dec 01 18:36:13 fallen-robot systemd[1]: Started Nightly snapshot backup job for ROOT volume.
Dec 01 18:36:13 fallen-robot systemd[75159]: schedule-backup_root.service: Failed to locate executable /usr/local/bin/backup.sh: Permission denied
Dec 01 18:36:13 fallen-robot systemd[75159]: schedule-backup_root.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/backup.sh: Permission denied
Dec 01 18:36:13 fallen-robot systemd[1]: schedule-backup_root.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 01 18:36:13 fallen-robot systemd[1]: schedule-backup_root.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nightly snapshot backup job for ROOT volume

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh -s / -b /run/media/borko/BackupTest/ -t "Fallen Robot ROOT Backup Report"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Why it cannot access the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable SElinux or set it to permissive.

```
setenforce 0
```

This will disable it temporarily. Test again after disabling it, and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: I solved it by sudo restorecon -rv /usr/local/bin/backup.sh. But I will accept your answer as it is on point!